# iOS: Presentation controller frame size changes on device orientation

Tags: ios, device-orientation, uipresentationcontroller

How to keep the presentation controller height same on device orientation change. Below is the code:

```
    func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController!, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return MyPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
    }

    class MyPresentationController : UIPresentationController {
        override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {

        let controllerHeight:CGFloat = 200.0
        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height

        return CGRect(x: 0.0, y: height - controllerHeight, width: width, height: controllerHeight)
        }
    }

    let pvc = MyPresentationController()
    pvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
    pvc.transitioningDelegate = self
```

[Here is the code sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gejjhmn11cxa3fl/TransitionSample.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the solution. Maybe not very intuitive but it works. Below is the code which will work in my sample.

I am dismissing and representing the controller on "viewWillTransition"

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        if let pvc = presentedViewController {
            pvc.dismiss(animated: true) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
// your presentedViewController
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "sampleSegue",
                                      sender: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```